# issue passing indexer into a call back

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

How would i pass an indexer from an outer for loop into a callback function within that for loop. My function within is the client.get() (see my code for desired output).

```
some_array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++){
    console.log(some_array[i]); // This prints a, b, c as expected
      client.get("http://foo/" + some_array[i] + "/bar", function (data, response) {
          console.log(some_array[i]); // THE PROBLEM: This prints undefind, I need it to print the exact same as the first console.log() statement
          console.log(i); // This also prints undefined
          console.log(some_array); // This prints ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
}
```

Since some_array is global i can print it just fine within the callback, however, i can not access any of the elements within some_array, how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of var for you incrementer..

```
for(let i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++){
  /// code here...
}
```

Since `let` is block scope it is the same anywhere in the block, even in an async function's callback.

Here's an example looping with an async function to demonstrate the differences.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];

for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("Using let", a[i]);
  }, 50);
}

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("Using var", a[i]);
  }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, could you share an example/article that highlights such behavior?

Comment: @Varinder - I did. That's a link in my first sentence..

Comment: yes, thanks, but I could not find details around ```let``` being the same within an async function's callback

Comment: @Varinder you could just try it :) ..i've added an example to demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: This is fantastic, it felt too good to be true, thanks for the example

Comment: That is awesome, thanks for the quick response @Occam's Razor. totally solved my problem!!

Comment: its nice when it's an easy fix :)